# MS Teams Not Working As Expected With and Github Action

Tags: microsoft-teams, github-actions

I am facing issue while sending notification to microsoft teams using below github action workflow YAML. As you can see in first job i am using right "ls -lrt" command and when this job1 succeeded then i got success notification in teams but to get failed notification, i purposefully removed hypen (-) from "ls lrt" command so that second job can fail and i can get fail notification. Overall idea is any job fail or success, i must get notification. But this is not happening for me actually. Any guidance and help would be appreciated.

```
name: msteams
on: push
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: test run
        run: ls -lrt
      - name: "testing_ms"
        if: always()
        uses: ./.github/actions

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: test run
        run: ls lrt
      - name: "testing ms"
        if: always()
        uses: ./.github/actions
```

As in above YAML you can see i am using **uses: ./.github/actions** so i kept below mentioned code in another YAML file and kept in **.github/actions** folder parallel to my above main github action workflow YAML.

```
name: 'MS Notification'
description: 'Notification to MS Teams'
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - id: notify
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo "This is for testing"
        # step logic
        # Specific to this workflow variables set
        PIPELINE_PUBLISHING_NAME="GitHub Actions Workflows Library"
        BRANCH_NAME="${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}"
        PIPELINE_TEAMS_WEBHOOK=${{ secrets.MSTEAMS_WEBHOOK }}
        # Common logic for notifications
        TIME_STAMP=$(date '+%A %d %B %Y, %r - %Z')  
        GITHUBREPO_OWNER=$(echo ${GITHUB_REPOSITORY} | cut -d / -f 1)
        GITHUBREPO_NAME=${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}
        GITHUBREPO_URL=${GITHUB_SERVER_URL}/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}
        SHA=${GITHUB_SHA}
        SHORT_SHA=${SHA::7}
        RUN_ID=${GITHUB_RUN_ID}
        RUN_NUM=${GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}
        AUTHOR_AVATAR_URL="${{github.event.sender.avatar_url}}"
        AUTHOR_HTML_URL="${{github.event.sender.url}}"
        AUTHOR_LOGIN="${{github.event.sender.login}}"
        COMMIT_HTML_URL="${GITHUBREPO_URL}/commit/${SHA}"
        COMMIT_AUTHOR_NAME="${{github.event.sender.login}}"
        case ${{ job.status }} in
          failure )
              NOTIFICATION_COLOR="dc3545"
              NOTIFICATION_ICON="&#x274C"
              NOTIFICATION_STATUS="FAILURE"
              ;;
          success )
              NOTIFICATION_COLOR="28a745"
              NOTIFICATION_ICON="&#x2705"
              NOTIFICATION_STATUS="SUCCESS"
              ;;
          cancelled )
              NOTIFICATION_COLOR="17a2b8"
              NOTIFICATION_ICON="&#x2716"
              NOTIFICATION_STATUS="CANCELLED"
              ;;
          *) 
              NOTIFICATION_COLOR="778899"
              NOTIFICATION_ICON=&#x2754""
              NOTIFICATION_STATUS="UNKOWN"
              ;;
        esac
        # set pipeline version information if available
        if [[ '${{ env.CICD_PIPELINE_VERSION}}' != '' ]];then 
          PIPELINE_VERSION="(v. ${{ env.CICD_PIPELINE_VERSION}})"
        else
          PIPELINE_VERSION=""
        fi
        NOTIFICATION_SUMARY="${NOTIFICATION_ICON} ${NOTIFICATION_STATUS} - ${PIPELINE_PUBLISHING_NAME} [ ${BRANCH_NAME} branch ] >> ${{ github.workflow }} ${PIPELINE_VERSION} "
        TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL="${PIPELINE_TEAMS_WEBHOOK}"
        # addtional sections can be added to specify additional, specific to its workflow, information 
        message-card_json_payload() {
          cat <<EOF
            {
                "@type": "MessageCard",
                "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
                "summary": "${NOTIFICATION_SUMARY}",
                "themeColor": "${NOTIFICATION_COLOR}",
                "title": "${NOTIFICATION_SUMARY}",
                "sections": [
                  {
                    "activityTitle": "**CI #${RUN_NUM} (commit [${SHORT_SHA}](COMMIT_HTML_URL))** on [${GITHUBREPO_NAME}](${GITHUBREPO_URL})",
                    "activitySubtitle": "by ${COMMIT_AUTHOR_NAME} [${AUTHOR_LOGIN}](${AUTHOR_HTML_URL}) on ${TIME_STAMP}",
                    "activityImage": "${AUTHOR_AVATAR_URL}",
                    "markdown": true
                  }
                ],
                "potentialAction": [
                  {
                    "@type": "OpenUri",
                    "name": "View Workflow Run",
                    "targets": [{
                        "os": "default",
                        "uri": "${GITHUBREPO_URL}/actions/runs/${RUN_ID}"
                        }]
                  },
                  {
                    "@type": "OpenUri",
                    "name": "View Commit Changes",
                    "targets": [{
                        "os": "default",
                        "uri": "${COMMIT_HTML_URL}"
                        }]
                  }
                ]
             }
        EOF
        }
        echo "NOTIFICATION_SUMARY ${NOTIFICATION_SUMARY}"
        echo "------------------------------------------------"
        echo "MessageCard payload"
        echo "$(message-card_json_payload)"
        echo "------------------------------------------------"
        HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
           --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" \
           --url "${TEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL}" \
           -d "$(message-card_json_payload)"
          )
        echo "------------------------------------------------"
        echo "HTTP_RESPONSE $HTTP_RESPONSE"
        echo "------------------------------------------------"
        # extract the body
        HTTP_BODY=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')
        # extract the status
        HTTP_STATUS=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
        if [ ! $HTTP_STATUS -eq 200  ]; then
          echo "::error::Error sending MS Teams message card request [HTTP status: $HTTP_STATUS]"
          # print the body
          echo "$HTTP_BODY"
          exit 1
        fi
```

Comment: As we can see you are getting the success notification when job1 succeeds and in order to get failed notification you are removing the '-', but you are not getting notification. Could you please confirm is there anything from Microsoft Teams side which is failing like json payload or anything that sort?

Comment: No, nothing like that... actually in GitHub action no error message like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the entire answer for you, but right off I see the composite action trying to read secrets, which composite actions don't support. Try setting input params to the composite actions to pass in what you need.